Why does "The Twelve Days of Christmas" have space complexity O(sqrt(n/log n))?
I've been reading Donald Knuth's "The Complexity of Songs", a "joke" paper about the space complexity of certain songs' lyrics (here's a link), for a bit of informal research. However, I ran into an issue where Knuth asserts, for "The Twelve Days of Christmas", that:

[there were] $\frac{1}{6}m^3+\frac{1}{2}m^2+\frac{1}{3}m$ gifts in $m$ days, so the complexity appeared to be $O(\sqrt[3]{n})$; however, it was soon pointed out that his computation was based on $n$ gifts rather than $n$ units of singing. A complexity of order $\sqrt{n/\log n}$ was finally established (see [7]).

I was able to obtain the $\sqrt[3]{n}$ figure, but am completely at a loss as to where the second one, the $\sqrt{n/\log n}$, comes from. The paper being a joke paper, the citation refers to a fictitious journal and is no help.
I computed the number of lyrics for "The $n$ Days of Christmas" for various values of $n$, which doesn't appear to corroborate either figure:
days,unique words,total words
1,17,18
2,22,40
3,26,65
4,30,93
5,34,124
6,38,158
7,42,195
8,46,235
9,50,278
10,54,324
11,58,373
12,62,425

So where does $\sqrt{n/\log n}$ come from?

Possibly related to the fact the English names of numbers don't have a bounded number of letters/syllables?

Interesting question just maybe 5 months too early in the year for this.  +1

"12 lords a leapin'" is 12 gifts and 1 unit of singing.  At the end of the first three days, there have been 6 units of singing and 10 gifts.

Disclaimer. There are two ways of describing the length of a song: length when written and time it takes to sing. In the first metric, the space complexity of the song is $\Theta(\sqrt{n/\log n})$, while in the second the space complexity is $\Theta(\sqrt n/\log n)$.

Let $k$ be the number of days, so that the number $N$ of gifts is $\Theta(k^3)$. We claim that the number of units (syllables) $M_1$ of singing is $\Theta(k^2\log^2k)$, while the number of units (characters) $M_2$ of writing is $\Theta(k^2\log k)$. In this way, the written space complexity is $k=\Theta(\sqrt{M_2/\log M_2})$, while the sung space complexity is $k=\Theta(\sqrt{M_1}/\log M_1)$. I expect that the remark uses written space complexity rather than sung space complexity.
We compute $M_1$ and $M_2$ by adding the units corresponding to the numbers (in the original song, just from "one" through "twelve") to all other units. For the "all other units" part, there are $\Theta(j)$ lines of song on day $j$, each of which has length (written or sung) $\Theta(1)$ when the number is removed. So, the number of non-numeric units is on the order of $1+2+\cdots+k=\Theta(k^2)$ in either case.
To count the syllables/characters in numbers, we use the following.
Proposition. To say a number $j$ requires $\Theta(\log^2j)$ syllables on average, while to write a number requires $\Theta(\log j)$ characters.
(The discrepancy is due to the fact that we write large numbers using digits, but when we say numbers, we say the corresponding power of $10$ every three digits, which corresponds most of the time to $\log j$ "words" each of which have $\log j$ syllables. Thanks to David K for pointing this out in the comments.)
Now, we say each number $1\leq j\leq k$ a total of $k+1-j$ times. So, the total number of syllables written/sung in numbers is on the order of
$$\sum_{j=1}^k(k+1-j)\log j\text{ and }\sum_{j=1}^k(k+1-j)\log^2j.$$
This is at most $k^2\log^tk$ and at least $(k^2/9)\log^t(k/3)$, where $t$ is $1$ if written and $2$ if sung (counting the terms with $k/3\leq j\leq 2k/3$), so it is on the order of $k^2\log^tk$.

"To say a number $j$ requires $\Theta(\log j)$ syllables." Have you attempted a proof of this claim? Consider the number of syllables in $10^n - 1$, keeping in mind that we don't just pronounce each digit; we also have to pronounce every third power of ten.

Ah -- good point. Seems like most numbers $j$ should take on the order of $(\log j)^2$ syllables? For now, I'll put a disclaimer at the top of the answer.

@DavidK I've fixed up the answer. After looking again at Knuth's paper, I think the complexity he describes is the complexity to write down the lyrics of the song, not to sing them. This is only different in some very strange cases, such as saying large numbers :)

I would still argue that time to sing is a better metric than space to write, but I think it's fairly clear that Knuth had the latter metric in mind. It was, after all, an April fool's paper, so no big deal, but I appreciate your thoroughness in representing both metrics.
